# Deal with trailing unit in Excel UDFs?

Tags: excel, excel-udf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Excel Built-in Functions on top of the UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784235/using-excel-built-in-functions-on-top-of-the-udf)

My Excel UDF currently returns a string which consists of numeric data and unit, e.g. `1234 kg`. It's straightforward and easy for users to read, but the problem is that it will hinder some basic calculations with Excel built-in functions, like `Sum()`, `Average()`, etc.

With the above formatting, i.e. `1234 kg`, using formula `=Sum()` will not bring the correct result unless the trailing unit `kg` is removed.

So my questions, is there any way that we could still allow calculations while keeping the units there? Can Excel identify `1234 kg` as a numeric value instead of a string value?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the number with string manipulation
`=VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" kg",A1)))`
will return 1234 from "1234 kg" in cell A1
but this means you have to manipulate the contents of the UDF cell

I would be simpler if:

- your UDF returned a numeric value (1234)
- then you apply a custom format to the cells with the UDF to add the " kg" while keeping the cell as a number (for example Custom Format of `#### " kg"`)